# select SVG item html

Tags: html, svg

I am exploring how to draw SVG items in html, I however cant find any clear example of how to select drawn objects by clicking on them (what I do know is that I need to use the objects ID)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vector framework for this: [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)